# separating substrings from a string in java

Tags: java

I have string which have following values(e.g). The each number in the string have comma followed by a space.

```
String var1 = 12, 4, 7, 125, 70;   
String var2 = 2, 5, 110, 25, 2;
```

Now I want to store the values in different varibales

```
For var1,
num1=12,
num2=4,
num3=7,
num4=125,
num5=70

For var2,
num1=2,
num2=5,
num3=110,
num4=25,
num5=2
```

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why different variables? Do you always have 5 numbers?

Comment: This is not compilable Java.

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
String[] numbers = var1.replaceAll(";","").split(", ");
String var1 = numbers[0];
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Grzegorz, it worked for me... :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
String var1 = "12, 4, 7, 125, 70";   
String var2 = "2, 5, 110, 25, 2";

String arr1[]=var1.split(",");
String arr2[]=var2.split(",");
```

and store it into separate variables.